# ePayment Processing Services and Salesforce

Tags: webservices, appexchange, connected-apps, app

I'm looking to interface with an external ePayment system from US Bank.  Is there an app in the app exchange that will allow customers in a portal to enter payment information?  Or should I just build a website to work with the ePayment service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are apps on the app exchange that provide connector services to external systems along with a lot of other features.

I don't know what US Banks payment processor is. But I have experience with `Linvio` and they connect to Authorize.net, Paypal, and a few other services.

I would suggest just shopping around on the App exchange and reaching out to anybody there that looks as if they have an app that could fit your needs.